# $p^3+q^3+r^3$, where $p$,$q$, and $r$ are the roots of the cubic function $x^3+4x^2-4x+1$. Working included.

Tags: roots

I am trying to utilise the expressions for Vieta's fomulae to solve expressions, just as an investigation. The question I gave myself is, if $p$, $q$, and $r$ are the roots of a cubic, what is $p^3+q^3+r^3$? The cubic is $x^3+4x^2-4x+1.$

I have done all the working out and come to the conclusion that the answer is $-115$. However, I am not 100% sure that my working out is correct, or if I used the formulae in the right way. If someone could check my working that I have attached as an image and point out any fundamental errors, that would be great. Thanks!

[WORKING HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6j1d.jpg)

Comment: There's no image.  But in any case, you should use MathJax rather than an image.

Comment: I have updated the post. Also, there are many lines of working and I'm new to Maths Stack Exchange so I feel that in this moment in time neat, written working is the most appropriate way to go :)

Comment: The correct answer is $-115$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015661/system-of-3-equations-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Here is an alternative approach.

You have
$$p^2+q^2+r^2=(\underbrace{p+q+r}_{=-4})^2-2(\underbrace{pq+pr+qr}_{=-4})=24,$$
By $x^3=-4x^2+4x-1$,
$$p^3+q^3+r^3=-4(p^2+q^2+r^2)+4(p+q+r)-(1+1+1)=-115.$$

Comment: Thank you for the quicker method, however I don't really understand if you used a formula for the first line, or if it's derived from elsewhere?

Comment: Expand $(p+q+r)^2=p^2+q^2+r^2+2pq+2pr+2qr$.

Comment: Ok thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, also, did you subsitute x=p+q+r, because I don't understand how $x^3=p^3+q^3+r^3$

Comment: Substitute $p,q,r$ separately, we get 3 equalities. Then add them together.

Comment: $\begin{cases}p^3=-4p^2+4p-1\\q^3=-4q^2+4q-1\\r^3=-4r^2+4r-1\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. You can also take a shortcut:
$$\begin{align}p+q+r&=-4 \Rightarrow \\
p+q&=-4-r \Rightarrow \\
(p+q)^3&=(-4-r)^3 \Rightarrow \\
p^3+q^3+3pq(p+q)&=-64-48r-12r^2-r^3 \Rightarrow \\
p^3+q^3+r^3&=-3\left(-\frac1r\right)(-4-r)-64-48r-12r^2=\\
&=-12r^2-48r-67-\frac{12}{r}=\\
&=\frac{-12(r^3+4r^2-4r+1)-115r}{r}=\\
&=-115,
\end{align}$$
because:
$$\begin{align}p+q+r&=-4;\\
pq+qr+rp&=-4;\\
pqr&=-1;\\
r^3+4r^2-4r+1&=0.\end{align}$$